# How do I add multiple urls to a wp_get_refererer?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a cf7 form that is connected to multiple pages on the site. How do I allow these pages to have access to one thank you page? I tried this code below but it doesnt work.

It doesnt work as in, only array[0] is getting redirected. Not the others.

I am still a noob with PHP so do pardon the logic

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
    $theOrigins = array(
'https://web1',
'https://web2',
'https://web3',
'https://web4',
    
    );
    
    $ref = wp_get_referer();


    // ID of the thank you page
    if (!is_page(1234)) {
        return;
    }

    // coming from the form, so all is fine
    if (in_array($ref, $theOrigins)) {
        return;
    }

    // we are on thank you page
    // visitor is not coming from form
    // so redirect to home
    wp_redirect(get_home_url());
    exit;
} );
```

Comment: “*it doesnt work*” isn’t a helpful problem statement, as it doesn’t provide the necessary detail to make any useful recommendations to you. How do you *know* it isn’t working? What did you expect to happen, and what is happening instead? See [ask]

Comment: doesnt work as in it only shows the page for one page but not the others in the array.